# Self-Executing Anonymous Functions Parameter From Outside Scope

Tags: javascript, function, dom-events, anonymous-function, self-invoking-function

I came across below code by following a tutorial.

```
const increment = (function(){
    return function incrementbytwo (number){
        return number+2;
    }
})();

console.log(increment(1));
```

The above outputs 3.

My problems are

1. How does the inner `incrementbytwo` receive a parameter from outside since it's a `Self-Executing Anonymous Functions`?
2. Step by step explanation of how this is executed.
3. What would be a real-world scenario to use a function like this?

Comment: `incrementbytwo` is not a self-executing function, and it's definitely not anonymous either. It is wrapped in a quite pointless immediately-executed function expression (IIFE), which could be simplified to `const increment = function incrementbytwo(numer) { … };`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my understanding of this:

I will start with #2 on your list, as it will make this easier. What you have, is a self-executing anonymous function that RETURNS a stored function.

1. You call to assign the `increment` constant to the returned result of the anonymous function's execution.
2. When the Anon function gets executed it returns the function `incrementbytwo` and THIS is assigned to your `increment` constant
3. You then call to execute the stored function within the `increment` constant, which is now incrementbytwo(number)

Your code above is just a standard function declaration with extra steps at declaration.

```
const increment = function increment(number){
        return number+2;
    }

console.log(increment(1));
```

There is no production use for this exact code scenario as far as I know (Roast me in the comments if I am wrong)

Answer (score 1):

1) The self executing IFFE results in the creating of a function statement being assigned to the `increment` identifier. It is exactly the same as:

```
const increment = function incrementbytwo (number){
    return number+2;
}
```

I should add, in case you don't know, that `increment` is block scoped to the enclosing code block (const), while `incrementbytwo` is function scoped to the function and is not accessible outside the function itself (due to the nature of the function expression).

2)

- 1) The right hand side is evaluated - and returns a function statement declaring `incrementbytwo(number)` that expects a number as a argument
- 2) The assignment of that function statement is made to `increment` (hence is a function expression. The function expression uses the same signature as the function statement - therefore takes a single argument that it passes into the function.
- 3) Calling increment(1) makes the magic happen.

3) There isn't one.